# How to us reduce() to build an object without cycling through multiple iterations

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm experimenting with `.reduce()` by building objects.

The code below successfully builds the object but it's wasteful.  `.reduce()` cycles through its loop 3 times because the array contains 3 items.  But the way I assign the keys and values `.reduce()` only needs to cycle through once. Is there a way to make `.reduce()` cycle just once or alternately is there a more efficient way to approach this problem?  Thanks for any input!

```js
"use strict";

var creatureArray = [];
var creatureObject = {}

creatureArray = ["Skeleton", "Sword", 10];

creatureObject = creatureArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index, array) => {
    accumulator[array[0]] = {
        weapon: array[1],
        damage: array[2]
    }
    return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(creatureObject);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to use `.reduce()` at all here. You seem to be anticipating the array having only those three items, so just assign them.

```js
"use strict";

var creatureArray = ["Skeleton", "Sword", 10];

var creatureObject = {
    [creatureArray[0]]: {
        weapon: creatureArray[1],
        damage: creatureArray[2]
    }
}

console.log(creatureObject);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm happy to know that I hit the wall on `.reduce()` and there isn't an obvious way to make it run more efficiently.  Your way is clearly more efficient because it only assigns the keys and values once.

Comment: Yeah, when you have a specific number of items used for a specific purpose, you can usually avoid looping. The `.reduce()` is most useful when you have an array that can be fully transformed into something else, but the number of its members is indeterminate.